# Лежит ли точка в 3D обьекте (выпуклый или вогнутый)

Tags: c, алгоритм, математика, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Нужна помощь по определению нахождения точки XYZ в трехмерном объекте построенным по XYZ точкам(к примеру КуБ) как с вогнутой стороной так и с выпуклой.
Для 2D отлично работает алгоритм луча с подсчетом пересечений как для вогнутых так и для выпуклых фигур: [ССЫЛКА](https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html#The%20C%20Code)

Есть ли похожий алгоритм для 3D или куда мне рыть,прошу вашей помощи)

Comment: Да, этот алгоритм хорошо будет работать для любых многогранников в пространстве. Аналогия полная: фиксируем луч, пересекаем его со всеми гранями. Если число пересечений нечетное - точка внутри.